# How to display local test report in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

My Test suite will generate a XML report and save it in my local machine. Is it possible to read XML report from my local machine and display it in as Jenkins logs.

Comment: What d g said is true... You shouldn't mix local and the actual deployment Test suites ...most of the times...What works locally, fails on the actual environment...Create a new job with those Test Suites

Answer (score 0):

Your flow seems backwards.

You should run your tests locally BEFORE Jenkins gets involved. Once it looks good locally, use some trigger like a git branch push to have Jenkins also run those tests and create the XML results file on the Jenkins server.

Within the job's configuration you can use a Jenkins plugin for the specific test framework you are using and it will automatically make your test results available within the job's output.

Search for the specific plugin and installation instructions here https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Plugins

Comment: I'm having SOAP SONAR script, after jenkins jobs , it is creating logs in the local where script is saved. In jenkins job it is just showing job is completed with the path where the log is stored. but Instead of that I want to print that log in jenkins